# Stripe Sigma Get Last Days Charges

Tags: stripe-payments, accounting

What I am trying to achieve I think is fairly simple yet it seems to be quite difficult to achieve with stripe Sigma. I would like to write a query to get all the charges for the last given day.

I am using `data_load_time` in my query but I noticed the data was last refreshed at `2022-11-20 12:00:00 +0000`. However in the docs I am sure it states data is only refreshed at 00:00:00 12AM not 12PM daily. I'm quite confused.

Therefore my data is returning half of one and half of the last. I simply want the full last days charges in my query.

So I need to modify my query to return the last full days of charges not half of one up to to 12PM the last day.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried the following query which returns data up to 12PM NOON the last day.

```
select
  charges.id,
  date_format(charges.created, '%m-%d-%Y') as day,
  charges.amount,
  customers.name,
  charges.shipping_address_line1,
  charges.shipping_address_city,
  charges.shipping_address_country,
  charges.shipping_address_postal_code
from
  charges
  inner join customers on customers.id = charges.customer_id
where
  charges.created < data_load_time
  and charges.created > data_load_time - interval '1' day
order by
  charges.created desc
```

Comment: Not sure where you see 00:00:00 from. As per documentation here, data refreshes at 12:00pm UTC in the following day: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-data/available-data

Comment: Maybe you can try with `date(data_load_time)` that is converted to the date itself.

Comment: @yuting Its states 'All API activity for a given day (from 12:00am to 11:59pm UTC) is available to query by 12:00pm UTC the following day' I'm sure that doesn't mean data right up until 12pm is available to be queried at 12pm. It means data up until 00:00:00 the past day is available to be queried at 12pm. My data is fresher. So data_load_time should always end at 00:00:00 In my case it doesn't.

Comment: My interpretation is that `data_load_time` refers to the timestamp when the data is loaded, not the timestamp of when the charges are for 12pm loading. In this case, the data is loaded at 12pm UTC for the data before 12am, so `data_load_time` will be 12pm. I'd recommend checking with Stripe Support to confirm.

Comment: In any case, if the `data_load_time` is `2022-11-20 12:00:00 +0000`, and you wish to retrieve data from `2022-11-19 00:00` to `2022-11-20 00:00`, it can be done with `charges.created < cast(data_load_time as Date) and charges.created > cast(data_load_time as Date) - interval '1' day`. This works for me.

Comment: Casting as date does seem to work. It is strange however because I do recall `data_load_time` in the past returning `00:00:00` for me and then it suddenly switched to `12:00:00`. It would be great to know why. But your example does work. Thanks